# Importing file from another folder in python

Tags: python-2.7, module, directory

Im using Python 2.7.
I got structure in PyCharm (all dirs are packages):

```
dirExa\
    dirBar\
        Bar.py
        __init__.py
    dirFoo\
        Foo.py
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
```

Now i want to import module called Bar.py in Foo.py

I used this (in file Foo.py):

```
from dirExa.dirBar import (some method)
```

but it gives me error such: No module dirFoo.dirBar import (some method)

Comment: You have no `__init__.py`s. You will need to decide whether `dirBar` and `dirFoo` should be two separate packages or a single one (in which case you can use intra-package imports). See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: I have __init__.py files in all my folders (dirExa, dirBar, dirFoo)
Sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: Then you probably want `from .dirBar import whatever_method`, but that will only work when you import the whole package (i.e. not if you try to run `Foo.py` directly). Please edit the question to actually be representative of your setup.

Comment: They are all saved as python packages with __init__.py insude each folder

Comment: U cant use from .dirBar